# ashx error http handler

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I'm getting the following error from the following http handler.
Other ashx files are working.
Tell me if you need more info...

```
Server Error in '/einUsername' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'WebApplication18.Handler1'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="Handler.ashx.cs" Class="WebApplication18.Handler1" %>

Source File: /einUsername/Handler.ashx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public partial class csIPNexample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // logging ipn messages... be sure that you give write
        // permission to process executing this code
        string logPathDir = ResolveUrl("Messages");
        string logPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.txt",
                         Server.MapPath(logPathDir), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        File.WriteAllText(logPath, "hi");
        //

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class in the error info is "WebApplication18.Handler1", however it is "csIPNexample" in the code you provided. Are you sure you posted correct code?

Comment: Yes, http://aspspider.net/einUsername%5cHandler1.ashx // ASP .NET C#
...
public partial class Handler1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        // logging ipn messages... be sure that you give write
        // permission to process executing this code
        string logPathDir = ResolveUrl("Messages");
        string logPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.txt",
                         Server.MapPath(logPathDir), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        File.WriteAllText(logPath, "hi");
        //

    }
}